# php_self and redirect in same page

Tags: php, page-refresh

Is it ok or standard to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` and `header('Location: http://www.example.com/form.php');` in the same page to avoid resubmitting the form on refresh.

I understand the concept of using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` on a page with a form, but then if I use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/form.php');` to avoid resubmitting to the db should I be redirecting to the same page.

I'm kinda confused.

**UPDATE:** Making it a bit more clear

I don't want to use the processing file name in form action (future proof - filename change, etc.), hence the use of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but now hitting refresh resubmits the form. To avoid that we go the PRG route, but redirecting it to the same page `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not solving the issue.

I wonder how others are doing it. Bottom line, I want to have my form and processing it in the same page without resubmission on refresh.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The two things have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Stano Your code made things a bit more clear. With your sample code, the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` being in the header, what goes in the form action? `<form action="what goes here" method="post">`

Comment: I think it should be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or just leave it empty.

Comment: @BernhardPoiss Nope, neither worked. Still getting resubmission on refresh.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is known as [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

You should redirect to that page that processes the input data, for example if your form action is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` you process the input data on the same page, so you redirect to the same page, if you want to process the input data on another page, than redirect to that page.

So, if

> should I be redirecting to the same page.

is a question. the answer is yes. And you maybe want to add some `GET` variables to show a "successfully sent" message, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard, I know about PRG. @Stano's code hit closer to home, maybe you can elaborate on my comment to him. It'll get me a step closer.